# I am unable to view the logs at http://localhost:9870/logs/

Tags: hadoop, logging, hdfs, resourcemanager

I am using the Hadoop HDFS resource manager(localhost:9870), and after successfully uploading files to HDFS, I am facing an issue where I cannot view the logs at http://localhost:9870/logs/. I checked the system's directory at C:\hadoop-3.2.4\hadoop-3.2.4\logs, but the logs are not being generated there either. Can anyone help me understand why the system is not generating and storing the logs?

I aim to generate HDFS logs for my project work. I've successfully uploaded files using a .bat file and the -put command. While the file upload process is functioning correctly, I'm encountering an issue where logs are not being generated at http://localhost:9870/logs/. I require the log data that this system should generate during its operation. I working on hadoop-3.2.4.